# Can I combine these CSV files into 1 larger CSV file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

My Old Bat file
    Copy F:\File.hdr+F:*.csv F:\FinalOutput.csv

the HDR file is a single entry file that has only header data for the CSV files

Is there a way to perform this in PowerShell (to combine all the CSV files into a single file)?

Here is my powershell script that doesn't work

```
$CSVFolder = 'F:\Input\';
$OutputFile = 'F:\Output\NewOutput.csv';    
$CSV= @();    
Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVFolder -Filter *.inv | ForEach-Object { 
    $CSV += @(Import-Csv -Path $CSVFolder\$_)
}    
$CSVHeader = Import-Csv 'F:\Input\Headings.hdr'    
$CSV = $CSVHeader + $CSV    
$CSV | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Force;
```

I get the list of FileNames that are exported and not the content of the Files.
The script is also modifying the date/time stamp on my INV files. It shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Should you perhaps be using `Get-Content` in place of `Import-Csv`?

Comment: Let me try that instead. Thank You

Comment: Well I changed Import-Csv to Get-Content and it works great  until I try to combine two $CSV = $CSVHeader + $CSV and the result is the Length. How would I combine the two files?

Comment: Try `$CSV = $CSVHeader , $CSV`

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the whole CSV bit if you just append the files as you would before.

Something like this should work:

```
# First we create the new file and add the header.
get-content $headerfile | set-content $outputfile

# Then we get the input files, read them out with get-content 
# and append them to the output file (add-content).
get-childitem -path $csvfolder *.inv | get-content | add-content $outputfile
```

The CSV commandlets are handy if you want to be processing the CSV data in your script, but in your case simply appending the files will do the trick. Not bothering with the CSV conversion will be a lot faster as Powershell doesn't have to parse the CSV lines and create PS-objects. It's really fast with pure text though.

Another trick here is how the get-content and add-content are used in the pipeline. Since they are aware of the pipeline you can pass in file objects without having to use a foreach loop. This makes your statements a lot shorter.

Comment: Thank you this works. One last thing to ask you. Some files had the first line as 0 (which is invalid data). Can we start remove the lines with 0 in it?

Comment: how do I not import the first line from the inv files?

Comment: Depends on what exactly the bad data looks like. If it's a zero like "0" you could use a `where -notlike "0*"` to filter out the data after the `get-content` statement (the "*" is a wildcard to match the rest of the line). This would then filter out all lines matching this pattern (so lines starting with the string "0") no matter where they appear in the file.

Comment: get-childitem -path $csvfolder *.inv | get-content where -notlike "0" | add-content $outputfile (produces an error)

Comment: Things are simpler if you use `import-csv` instead of `get-content`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
get-childitem *.inv | foreach-object {
  import-csv $_ -header (get-content Headings.hdr)
} | export-csv NewOutput.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: I have one file that is an HDR file (it contains the header info and needs to be the first line of the newly created file

Comment: So add `-header` to `import-csv`. See my amended answer.